# Flink: Data aggregation based on key with deduplication

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Problem Statement:

I am trying to build a flink job to aggregate (say average speed) by category (i.e., carModel) along with deduplication of the data based on an id (i.e., carNumber).

Data Details:
My data contains the following structure:

```
Class CarSpeedData() {
String carNumber;
String carModel;
Integer speed;
}
```

Any data with same `carNumber` should be removed if within a certain window (say 30 seconds).

I have got aggregation working using Keyed state](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#using-keyed-state).

```
DataStream input = env.fromElements(
        new CarSpeedData("id1", "Civic", 40), 
        new CarSpeedData("id2", "Corolla", 45), 
        new CarSpeedData("id3", "Civic", 47), 
        new CarSpeedData("id4", "Civic", 46), 
        new CarSpeedData("id1", "Civic", 40), 
        new CarSpeedData("id5", "Corolla", 52), 
        new CarSpeedData("id6", "Corolla", 62), 
        new CarSpeedData("id7", "Camary", 70)
    );

    input.keyBy(value -> value.getCarModel())
    .flatMap(new RollingAverage()) // RollingAverage is implementation of Keyed state
    .print();
```

I also have window based deduplication working using [TimeToLive state](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl).

```
input.keyBy(value -> value.getCarNumber()) // refer the input above
    .flatMap(new DuplicateFilter()) // DuplicateFilter is implementation of TTL state
    .print();
```

However, I am not able to combine the two, as both operate on different fields.

I have tried to put the two operations one after another:

```
input.keyBy(value -> value.f1)
        // Filter duplicate
        .keyBy(value -> value.getCarNumber())
        .flatMap(new DuplicateFilter())
        // Now try the aggregation
        .keyBy(value -> value.getCarModel())
        .flatMap(new RollingAverage())
        .print();
```

In this, since the first keyby is by car number, the aggregation does not have the state even when two cars have same model and both have old state as zero.

Any suggestions to this?